# PGAdmin 4 - server status / view log file

Tags: pgadmin

I recently upgraded to Postgresql 9.6 and PgAdmin 4.

Now, one handy feature of PgAdmin 3 was the "server status" window, which I used to look at the log file.

I can't find that in PgAdmin 4. How can I view the server log in PgAdmin 4? Or is there a nice alternative?

Comment: vim is a decent alternative

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have followed the guide [here](https://www.hagander.net/blog/remote-log-reading-in-postgresql-91-192/) to use a [foreign data wrapper](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/file-fdw.html) so I can access the log file through SQL.

First, create the extension:

```
create extension file_fdw;
```

Next, set up postgres.conf to support [csv logging](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-LOGGING-CSVLOG). Essentially, these settings:

> log_destination='csvlog'
>
> logging_collector='on'
>
> log_filename='postgresql.log'

And also the following, from the documentation:

> Set log_filename and log_rotation_age to provide a consistent,
>   predictable naming scheme for your log files. This lets you predict
>   what the file name will be and know when an individual log file is
>   complete and therefore ready to be imported.
>
> Set log_rotation_size to 0 to disable size-based log rotation, as it
>   makes the log file name difficult to predict.
>
> Set log_truncate_on_rotation to on so that old log data isn't mixed
>   with the new in the same file.

Create, the server and the table, and the log can be queried!

```
create server logserver FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER file_fdw;

CREATE FOREIGN TABLE postgres_log
(
  log_time timestamp(3) with time zone,
  user_name text,
  database_name text,
  process_id integer,
  connection_from text,
  session_id text,
  session_line_num bigint,
  command_tag text,
  session_start_time timestamp with time zone,
  virtual_transaction_id text,
  transaction_id bigint,
  error_severity text,
  sql_state_code text,
  message text,
  detail text,
  hint text,
  internal_query text,
  internal_query_pos integer,
  context text,
  query text,
  query_pos integer,
  location text,
  application_name text)
SERVER logserver OPTIONS (filename 'pg_log/postgresql.csv', format 'csv');

select message from postgres_log;
```

Comment: should be `log_filename='postgresql`, NOT `postgresql.log`

Comment: Thanks for answering your own question :D