# Equivalent of PGAdmin III Server Status Activity Window in PGAdmin 4 v5

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4, postgresql-13

I'm in the process of upgrading to Postgres 13.2 from a much older version.  This entails an upgrade from PGAdmin III to PGAdmin 4.

PGAdmin III has a brilliantly designed feature called Server Status Activity Window which lists all open connections on a server.  If you sort the connections by the "Query Start" column (descending) you can see the connections that have the longest-running queries.  The rows are color coded: active connections are initially green, then after a query is running for 10-15 seconds it turns brown.  Idle queries are blue.  The autovacuum queries are usually sitting in brown color because they tend to run for a while.

So with PGAdmin III Server Status Activity Window, a dba can quickly spot queries that have been running for a long time.

PGAdmin 4 v5 has something similar called "Server Activity" but it falls short.  Only the connection start timestamp is available as a column that can be sorted by.  You have drill into the connection details to see the "Query Start" timestamp and you can't sort by it.

What work-arounds are available in PGAdmin 4 v5 to get this view that was available in PGAdmin III?

A related question appears here: [PGAdmin 4 - server status / view log file](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/153904/pgadmin-4-server-status-view-log-file)

Comment: I just noticed that in PGAdmin4 v5.5 a new color-coding feature has been added that identifies connections with long-running queries in the "Server Activity" window on the "Dashboard" tab by highlighting connection in a different color.  There is a setting that configures the "Warning" and "Alert" thresholds.  The units for this setting are in MINUTES.  I wish that the default units were measured in SECONDS instead.

Comment: Referring to my comment above, it appears that the "Warning" and "Alert" thresholds will accept decimals, so you can enter ".25" if you want a threshold to be 15 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this query that returns the same columns as PGAdmin III Status Activity window but alas there is no color-coding of queries running longer than 5-10 seconds and no button that will terminate the query or the connection.

```
select pid as process_id, 
       application_name,
       datname as Database,
       usename as username, 
       client_addr as client_address, 
       backend_start as client_start,
       query_start,
       xact_start,
       state,
       state_change,
       pg_blocking_pids(pid) AS blocked_by,
       query
from pg_stat_activity
where state is not null 
order by state,xact_start desc;
```

This query is based loosely on this [post](https://dataedo.com/kb/query/postgresql/list-database-sessions) and this [post](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/big_data_and_business_intelligence/9781785883187/8/ch08lvl1sec112/knowing-who-is-blocking-a-query)